# Having trouble with BIRT 4.3 new POJO DataSource

Tags: java, birt

I am following the example at http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable4.3.php#jump_3
and I can't seem to get it to work properly.  At the step where you define the new DataSet (New Birt POJO Data Set), I can't seem to find the 'POJO Data Set Class Name'.  The matching item widget remains empty.  I tried editing the rptdesign with the source tab trying all kind of variations (with/without package name), nothing does it.  Anybody had success with this new feature of BIRT ?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, my bad.  It would have been easier if we had to implement an interface rather than trying to deduce how birt reads a custom pojo dataset.

So on the example at http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable4.3.php#jump_3 everything worked as described except for the class CustomerDataSet.  Here is the implementation of the class CustomerDataSet that worked for me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomerDataSet {

public Iterator<Customer> itr;

public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    Customer c = new Customer(103);
    c.setCity("City1");
    c.setCountry("Country1");
    c.setCreditLimit(100);
    c.setName("aName1");
    c.setState("state1");
    customers.add(c);

    c = new Customer(104);
    c.setCity("City2");
    c.setCountry("Country2");
    c.setCreditLimit(200);
    c.setName("aName2");
    c.setState("aStat2");
    customers.add(c);

    c = new Customer(105);
    c.setCity("City3");
    c.setCountry("Country3");
    c.setCreditLimit(300);
    c.setName("aName3");
    c.setState("aStat3");
    customers.add(c);

    return customers;
}

public void open(Object obj, Map<String,Object> map) {
}

public Object next() {
    if (itr == null)
        itr = getCustomers().iterator();
    if (itr.hasNext())
        return itr.next();
    return null;
}

public void close() {
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. I think the iterator should be private, and initialized in "open" method rather in next().

Comment: @ Francois Lacoursiere    In my case I can not see the Data source class name in data source.Plz If you have faced the problem plz help me.

Comment: I've been trying to deduce, and I've deduced it. You need object with `public Object next()` method. It goes through this converter https://eclipse.googlesource.com/birt/org.eclipse.birt/+/f991893c494cfacc508f7dab9e1b6a7d2e00d5fc/data/org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.pojo/src/org/eclipse/birt/data/oda/pojo/impl/internal/PojoDataSetFromCustomClass.java